# NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure resteasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to use resteasy with custom object it works fine with intellij IDE when i create a jar file it fails with the below exception

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: UserInfo of media type: application/json
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My resource method looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getTest(String userInfos) {
    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
    info.setUserID("example");
    info.setEnabled(true);
    return  Response.ok().entity(info).build();
}
```

UserInfo.java:

```
 public class UserInfo {
        public String userID;
        public Boolean enabled;

        public String getUserID() {
            return userID;
        }

        public void setUserID(String userID) {
            this.userID = userID;
        }

        public Boolean getEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }
    }
```

Not sure why?

Comment: Can you add more information - e.g. what are you deploying to? java version? libraries in use?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have the jackson provider included add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.14.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also hit this issue and found that it was caused by a mishandling of the META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers files when creating an Uber jar.

Full details can be [found here](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2015/03/24/what-to-do-when-jax-rs-cannot-find-its-providers-aka-my-message-body-writer-is-not-used/), but the main problem is the files are overwritten by each other rather than concatenated so that if you have MessageBodyWriter's from multiple jars, only those from the last one are registered.  I was using gradle to build my uber Jar and solved the problem by adding the following:

```
shadowJar {
  mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

For maven, the maven-shade-plugin should also be able to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0):

The message body readers are discovered automatically based on the classpath of your application(by default) or can be registered manually. Depending on the application server and deployment structure you use, the specific message body reader might not be available. Commonly used providers with *application/json* capabilities are  *resteasy-jackson-provider*, *resteasy-jettison-provider*. Verify that at least one of these is available in your classpath.

Also can you check that you have not disabled provider discovery in the web.xml?

```
 <context-param>  
     <param-name>resteasy.use.builtin.providers</param-name>  
     <param-value>true</param-value>  
   </context-param>
```

If that does not help, can you provide more details on how you package your app, where do you deploy it, and some relevant configuration files?